# Find parent branch from a commit id

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a commit that will list out all branches which has this particular commit

Ex: a769h689 -> This commit id is available in branch1,branch2,branch3,branch4

But I would like to know if I want to find from which branch this commit a769h689 has been originated from?

I couldn't find a suitable answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "originated from"? for example: If I have a branch, then move it to a commit elsewhere, where did that branch originate?

Comment: Do you have an example git tree we can look at? Or maybe you could tell us what you expect?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, updated with comments

Comment: You can find out if two commits share a common commit ancestor, but please know that a branch is a temporary pointer which has no history of its own.

Comment: You can't answer this question. If a commit is contained in multiple branches, there's no way to tell in which one it originated: the history of each branch is equally valid and there's no way to tell which came first.

Answer (score 0):

There are version control systems that provide this information.  In these VCSes, a commit records which branch it was made on, or—even more commonly—when a commit is made on some branch, *that* branch is *the* branch the commit is on, from then on.  Each commit is thus on exactly one branch, forever.<sup>1</sup>

Git is not such a version control system.  In Git, any commit is on zero or more branches at any time.  The number of branches that contain the commit changes dynamically as branch names are created, destroyed, or moved.  Git declares that the information about which branch—if any—was the current branch *when* the commit was created is of no value whatsoever, or perhaps even has *negative* value, and therefore does not save it.

If you, as the creator of some commit, wish to save additional information *with* that commit, you can do so, in the commit log message.  But Git itself is no help at all here.  Note that it's possible that the commit was created on *no branch at all:* this is the case during rebase operations, for instance.  (A rebase works by copying commits; the original commits are then discarded in favor of the copies.  The copies themselves are made in what Git calls *detached HEAD* mode, where there is no branch.  Obviously if Git were to record which branch was current, rebase would have to operate differently, but given that this *is* how it operates, be careful if you try to automate adding current-branch information to commit messages.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Mercurial, for instance, works this way.